# OpenCV cannot open video file

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I use

```
cv::VideoCapture video(mp4name);
```

But

```
video.isOpened()==false;
```

I use OpenCV 3.4.1.
Any ideas?

Thanks,

Yair

Comment: What is the path value of `mp4name`? do you have the video file in that path?

Comment: 1. Try to set a full path to the video. 2. If you work on Windows then copy opencv_ffmpeg341.dll (or opencv_ffmpeg341_64.dll) to the binary directory.

Comment: Thanks Nuzhny! indeed I needed opencv_ffmpeg341_64.dll